# Bound functions and decorators in python

Tags: python, decorator

I am trying different things to understand Decorators and functions in Python.
Is the below code correct way :

```
import math
def calculate_area(func):
    def area(a,b):
        return a+b
    return area

class Donut():
    def __init__(self, outer, inner):
        self.inner = inner
        self.outer = outer

    @calculate_area
    @staticmethod
    def area(self):
        outer, inner = self.radius, self.inner
        return Circle(outer).area() - Circle(inner).area()
```

Will "staticmenthod" decorator tells the built-in default metaclass type (the class of a class, cf. this question) to not create bound methods ? 
is it possible to do :

```
Donut.area(4,5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#33>", line 1, in <module>
Donut.area(4,5)
TypeError: unbound method area() must be called with Donut instance as first argument      (got int instance instead)
```

Please help me in understanding bound methods and unbound methods and what it the impact of decorator on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just swap the @staticmethod with your decorator

```
import math
def calculate_area(func):
    def _area(a, b):
        return a + b
    return _area

class Donut():
    def __init__(self, outer, inner):
        self.inner = inner
        self.outer = outer

    @staticmethod
    @calculate_area
    def area(cls):
        outer, inner = self.radius, self.inner
        return ""
```

EDIT 1:

python interpreter requires to add @staticmethod at before another decorators, because , before creating a class type ,its need to determines the class members and instance members.if your first decorator is anything else ,interpreter known this function as  an instance member. see [this](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#motivation)

EDIT 2:

it's recommended to use @classmethod instead @staticmethod, for more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)

Comment: An explanation of why this works and OP's code doesn't would be nice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and making me understand . I just have 1 question : does _ in _area() means something specific ?

Comment: in python standard naming convention, we add one underscore, to specify protected members, for private members use __(double underscore).